# Async Pipe on nested array

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngfor

I am having trouble understanding how to use the angular async pipe on my Observable.

[My Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vlvv8i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fhomepage%2Fhomepage.component.ts)

My Observable has this structure Observable<HttpResponse<Books[]>>

```
export class HttpResponse {
  status: string | undefined;
  data: any;
  success: string | undefined;
  message: string | undefined;
}
```

The data would contain an array of book objects.

```
export interface Book {
 id: string;
 volumeInfo: {
 title: string;
 authors: Array<string>;
};
```

}

I can get it working without using the async pipe, by just assigning each value to a variable books[] . Maybe I am using the async pipe wrong with books$ ? I need to be iterating on the response.data array not on the response.

[image]

homepage.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from '../../models/books';
import { BooksService } from '../../services/books.service';
import { HttpResponse } from '../../models/httpresponse';
import { Observable, of, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css'],
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[] = [];       // This works.
  books$: Observable<Book[]>;    // Can't get async pipe to work with this.

  constructor(private booksService: BooksService) {
    this.books$ = this.booksService.getBooks().pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        // TESTING
        console.log(
          `homepage.component - books$ - Status: ${response.status} Success: ${response.success} Data:`,
          response.data
        );
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.booksService
      .getBooks()
      .pipe(
        tap((response: any) => {
          // TESTING
          console.log(
            `homepage.component - books - Status: ${response.status} Success: ${response.success} Data:`,
            response.data
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe((response: HttpResponse) => {
        response.data.forEach((val: any) => {
          this.books.push(Object.assign({}, val));
        });
      });
  }
}
```

homepage.component.html :

```
<div class="layout">
  <div>
    <h2>Books</h2>
    <p *ngFor="let b of books">
      {{ b.volumeInfo.title! }} - {{ b.volumeInfo.authors! }}
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Books</h2>
    <p>Error here using async pipe?</p>
    <p>I want it to be the same as above.</p>
    <ul>
      <ng-container *ngIf="books$ | async as books">
        <li *ngFor="let b of books | keyvalue">{{ b.key }}: {{ b.value }}</li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: replace tap with map and return response.data

Comment: I can't add an answer because I just answered another but....it is because you are returning the response. You need to map it out.
this.books$ = this.booksService.getBooks().pipe(map(response => response.data));
Then you can call it just like you do on top without the keyvalue pipe. EDIT: Lol yep, what @SOisfullofMonkeys said.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change and I can see if works but how dows the ngFor and the keyvalue pipe work to list the {{b.volumeInfo.title!}} ? It says volumeInfo not found.

Comment: I might need several ngFor statements maybe?